# Bootstrap adding a dropdown caret

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih9GU.png

As indicated above, I want to learn to make a dropdown menu with the "dropdown-caret" (circled green in the image).
I viewed source of twitter and it seems that they have it as `<li class="dropdown-caret"></li>`, but I couldn't produce it using the Bootstrap.
Is this not included in the bootstrap, or am I doing it wrongly?

In addition, how do I align the dropdown menu to left instead of the default right? As shown in the image, the dropdown menu is aligned to left.

Comment: Post some code? Maybe a JSFiddle?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051269/whats-the-mystery-of-the-boostrap-dropdown-menu-triangle)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap adds the caret by default if you are using dropdowns within a navigation bar. These are the CSS rules:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #CCC;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

So make sure you have this DOM structure or copy the style.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! for future reference, did you have to look through the css file to find this feature?

Comment: I used Chrome dev tools to inspect the code in http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Popover functionality in bootstrap

[Found Docu here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

Here you can see, how it works.

Comment: popover is not a dropdown.